# Net Core 2.1 Angular project set up SSR config with Angular CLI 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli, asp.net-core-2.1, server-side-rendering

I've created an angular application using the new Net Core 2.1 Angular template build in in Visual Studio 2017. This template uses a pure angular-cli setup in favor of the previous webpack config.

The template uses angular 5.2 so I upgraded it to 6 using the [official update guide](https://update.angular.io/). After some additional tweaks like removing the "--extract-css" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50754060/782598), the application worked like a charm again.

For SEO purpose I wanted to activate SSR so I used the [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#server-side-rendering) provided by MS. This guide works when using Angular CLI 5 (used it before the migration) but I don't know how to do this with Angular CLI 6.

The ".angular-cli.json" has of course been replaced by the "angular.json" file which has another setup. So I am a bit puzzled as how to set this up.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "xxx",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Templating/issues/593) topic on github which explains the actions needed to activate SSR for angular CLI 6 in combination with NET Core.
This explains a lot and they will update the original [info page](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#server-side-rendering) soon.